# Communicating beteween parent and child with row ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to call a parent function from a child function.

I follow this example :[Expose Component Functions](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/expose-component-functions.html) but with this code my page does not load and my console is empty so i do not know find the problem.

I use webpack with babel and webpack-dev-server

Thank you for your answers.

I am sorry for my english.

```
class Row extends React.Component {
  render(){
      return(
        <tr className="animated slideInRight">
        <th scope="row">{this.props.data.ville_id}</th>
        <td>{this.props.data.ville_nom}</td>
        <td>{this.props.data.ville_nom_reel}</td>
        <td>{this.props.data.ville_canton}</td>
        <td><button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.props.onClick} >Full Detail</button></td>
        </tr>
      )
  }
}

export default class Metier extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      data: [],
    };
  }
   deleteClick(e){
      console.log("ici")
  }

  render(){
    return(
            <table className="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>IdVille</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      {this.state.data.map(function(result,i){
                        var boundClick = this.deleteClick.bind(this,i)
                        return(
                          <Row onClick={boundClick} key={i} data={result} />
                        )
                      })}
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
 )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the arrow function in the map so you can access `this`:

```
{this.state.data.map((result,i) => {
    var boundClick = this.deleteClick.bind(this,i)
    return(
        <Row onClick={boundClick} key={i} data={result} />
    )
})}
```

By using a simple function you create a new context and in that function you cannot access `this.deleteClick`. Using an arrow function you can still access it.